# Did Emperor Pushyamitra Shunga persecute Buddhists?

Tags: ancient-history, ancient-india

Did Emperor [Pushyamitra Shunga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushyamitra_Shunga) persecute Buddhists?

Comment: Did you see the sub-article [Authenticity of the Buddhist claims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushyamitra_Shunga#Authenticity_of_Buddhist_claims) on the same page as you linked here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Wikipedia page cites several controversies about the alleged Buddhist persecutions.  [Simmons & Sarao, 2010](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushyamitra_Shunga#CITEREFSimmonsSarao2010) is mentioned in the wikipedia page and bibliography as one contrary opinion.  There are several others mentioned on that page.